# Is there an EXCEL formula that counts how many times Excel data 'switches' between binomial coding (i.e., data coded as 1 or 2)?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Folks, would really appreciate some help;

If I have the following values of data in Excel (3 examples below) where data is coded as 1 or 2, does anyone know an Excel formula which can count how many 'switches' occur in the sequence of values? What I mean by a 'switch', is when the 1's switch to 2's, and vice versa (when the 2's switch to 1's).

For example;

> 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2 (there is 1 switch here)

> 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 (there are two switches here)

> 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2 (there are three switches here)

So far, I am able to use the following formula (see below) to see IF there is a switch at all in the sequence (from 2 to 1 for example). But now I am trying to calculate how many switches are occurring in the sequence, and not IF a singular switch is occurring. So I think I possibly need to use a COUNT formula, instead of a FIND formula?

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND("21",TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,[data range of a row]))),FALSE,TRUE)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is `1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2` entered as a string in a single cell or as values in a range of cells?

Comment: Hey Enigmativity, they are values in a range of cells!

Comment: Can you please fix the question to make that clear? You refer to them as "strings of data".

Comment: Hopefully that's clearer now

Comment: Oh well I best remove my answer, completely irrelevant :D

Comment: So sorry Jamheadart, that was completely my fault :( !! Thank you for what you provided anyway, I really appreciate it !1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have your data in cells `A1` to `I1`, then use this formula:

```
=SUM(ABS(B1:I1-A1:H1))
```

I've tested this with your three inputs and it produces the expected answers.

Answer (score 0):

If you would have access to `FILTERXML` (I believe from Excel 2013 onwards) you could use:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=COUNT(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,", ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[following::*[1]!=.]"))
```

For your understanding; the xpath expression `//s[following::*[1]!=.]` will return all (child)nodes where the first following node is different then the current one. Then `COUNT` will actually count these returned numbers. Note that this will return `0` when no change occurs in your string.